# Laravel 5 Update Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a working crud code in laravel but my problem is the validation. Here is my code:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $room_id =  $this->route('route');
    $validator = \Validator::make(\Request::all(), [
        'roomNumber' => 'required|unique:rooms,roomNumber,',
        'type' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    if(!$validator -> fails()){
        $id  = \Request::input('id');
        $com = Room::find($id);

        $room -> roomNumber = \Request::input('roomNumber', 'Test');
        $room -> type = \Request::input('type', 'Test');
        $room -> price = \Request::input('price', '0.00');
        $room -> description = \Request::input('description', 'Test');

        $com -> save();

        return redirect('rooms') -> with('message', 'Room Updated!');
    } else {
        return redirect('rooms') -> withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
}
```

As you can see, the roomNumber is required and should be unique. My problem is, this is the update code. What if I just want to update some field like the `price` or the `type`? Whenever I update a field I always get `The room number has already been taken.` in my view because yes, the roomNumber should be unique in my validation.

How can I update a specific field that will still check if the `room number` is unique but if the data I'm updating is in the same field, it will just update the other fields like the `type` and `price`? Please correct me if my question is vague. Thank you!

Example:

I have 2 data's in my rooms table

```
Data 1:
roomNumber: 214
type: Queen
price: 150.00

Data 2:
roomNumber: 619
type: Suite
price: 250.00
```

Now if I update the `Data 1` field `price` from `150.00` to `160.00`, I will get the validation error `The room number has already been taken.` because it will also validate the `roomNumber` when I update. How can I update it without validating the `roomNumber` if the data I'm updating is the same?

Comment: sorry can you clarify this a bit more when you say "..but if the data I'm updating is in the same field, it will just update the other fields like the type and price". Can you give an example ?

Comment: @codegeek Updated my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to create a custom request class as follows. you can put this in a separate file called `RoomRequest.php`

```
use app\Http\Requests\Request;

class RoomRequest extends Request
 {
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; //or check auth here
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $room_id =  $this->input('id');
        return [
         'roomNumber' => 'required|unique:rooms,roomNumber','.$room_id',
       //whatever else
    ];
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, use this request class above

```
   public function update(RoomRequest $request)
    {
        $id  = $request->input('id');
        $room = Room::find($id);

        $room -> roomNumber = $request->input('roomNumber', 'Test');
        $room -> type = $request->input('type', 'Test');
        $room -> price = $request->input('price', '0.00');
        $room -> description = $request->input('description', 'Test');

        $room-> save();

        return redirect('rooms') -> with('message', 'Room Updated!');
    }
```

This ensures that Laravel will exclude existing ids from the validation which you want.

Comment: Undefined variable: room

Comment: see my edit. you need to create a Request and then use in controller

Comment: Thanks much! If this is my code http://pastebin.com/XMRaUYvR, what will it look now when I will add the RoomRequest?

Comment: Tried and got this one Class App\Http\RoomRequest does not exist. I created a RoomRequest.php inside the Request folder and put your code, and then in my controller use App\Http\RoomRequest;

Comment: No. Put the controller file and this RoomRequest.php file in the same folder. Then namespace. I can help on chat if needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92633/discussion-between-fewflyby-and-codegeek).

Answer (score 1):

Here check the documentation.

[Laravel Unique Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

You can ignore an given value. So your validation can still check if it is not a duplicate but will ignore that one value.

See here an example:

```
'email'     => 'required|unique:Management,email,' . $this->route('management')
```

With the $this->route('management') I get the ID of the management record that i'm currently try to update. So this ID will be ignored.

See also my route list here:

```
| GET|HEAD | admin/management
| GET|HEAD | admin/management/create
| PUT      | admin/management/{management}
| DELETE   | admin/management/{management}
| PATCH    | admin/management/{management}
| GET|HEAD | admin/management/{management}
| GET|HEAD | admin/management/{management}/edit
```

Comment: I'm getting Method [route] does not exist.

Comment: You should put this code in your Request class not in your controller. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches. Check form request validation.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to validate unique of primary key in create method, in update method, you don't have to validate uniqueness again since it will definitely failed all the time.

If you update an existing record which has been check unique in create method, then no need to check it again.

Regards,